# how to make lightning button using css

Tags: css

I have a button and I need it to be lightning on hover

```
    .button {
    font-size: 16px;
    position: relative;
    top: 20%;
    background: #fcffdc;
    color: #de204f;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 20px 14px 20px;
  &:hover {
    background: #fcffdc;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: -4px -4px 4px rgba(250, 0, 20, 0.4);
```

But it has only a shadow in front of the button. How do a shadow all over the button?

Comment: use `:hover` selector and apply your css rules to it. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Comment: do you mean highlight?

Comment: what do you mean by shadow all over the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in chrome dev tools you can edit `box-shadow` property using visual editor, 
it's quite useful and you can build whatever shadow you'd like.

[image]

for current case don't forget to toggle `:hover` element state

[image]

and here's your code

```css
.button {
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
  top: 20%;
  background: #fcffdc;
  color: #de204f;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color .4s;
}

.button:hover {
  color: white;
  background: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(250, 0, 20, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<a class='button'>Hello</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
 <style>
 .button {
    font-size: 16px;
    position: relative;
    top: 20%;
    background: #fcffdc;
    color: #de204f;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 20px 14px 20px;
  }
.button:hover {
 background: #fcffdc;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px rgba(250, 0, 20, 0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px 2px rgba(250, 0, 20, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px rgba(250, 0, 20, 0.4);
}
```

```html
 
 </style>
 <html>
 <button type="button" class="button">Click Me!</button>
 </html>
```

Try

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px rgba(250, 0, 20, 0.4);
-moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px 2px rgba(250, 0, 20, 0.4);
box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px rgba(250, 0, 20, 0.4);
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
  .button {
    font-size: 16px;
    position: relative;
    top: 20%;
    background: #fcffdc;
    color: #de204f;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 20px 14px 20px;
}
  .button:hover {
    background: #fcffdc;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(250, 0, 20, 0.4);
    }
```

```html
<button class="button">click here</button>
```

Use `box-shadow` css as `box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(250, 0, 20, 0.4);`